# (PHP) Image Resize failed

Tags: php, image, resize

**I try to resize an image, but I still get the same error:**

> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dad/gallery.php on line 18

> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): 'img/test/Bildschirmfoto 2014-01-25 um 08.05.13 nachm Kopie.jpg' is not a valid JPEG file in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dad/gallery.php on line 18

> Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dad/gallery.php on line 19

> Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dad/gallery.php on line 20

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dad/gallery.php on line 24

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dad/gallery.php on line 24

> Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dad/gallery.php on line 25

> Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dad/gallery.php on line 25

> Warning: imagecopyresized() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dad/gallery.php on line 25

**So, here's my code:**

```
function make_thumb($image_path, $thumb_path, $thumb_width) { 
    $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg("$image_path"); 
    $origw=imagesx($src_img); 
    $origh=imagesy($src_img); 
    $new_w = $thumb_width; 
    $diff=$origw/$new_w; 
    $new_h=$new_w; 
    $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_w,$new_h); 
    imagecopyresized($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$new_w,$new_h,imagesx($src_img),imagesy($src_img)); 
    imagejpeg($dst_img, "$thumb_path"); 
    RETURN TRUE; 
}
```

Comment: _'img/test/Bildschirmfoto 2014-01-25 um 08.05.13 nachm Kopie.jpg' is not a valid JPEG file_ <- that's it.

Comment: oh, well... whats it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error the resource is not an valid jpg as the error state, and the following errors after that just a chain.

I would suggest you to use this Library I wrote on [PHP image upload, resize and crop called eImage](https://github.com/falmar/eImage#resize-image)

Try this code Instead:

```
function make_thumb($image_path, $thumb_path, $thumb_width) {
    $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg("$image_path");
    $origw=imagesx($src_img);
    $origh=imagesy($src_img);

    // This calculations goes is for?
    // note that diff is not being used
    $new_w = $thumb_width;
    $diff = $origw/$new_w;
    $new_h = $new_w;
    // end of calculation
    $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($new_w,$new_h);
    imagecopyresampled($canvas,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$new_w,$new_h,$origw,$origh);
    imagejpeg($canvas, $thumb_path);
    imagedestroy($src_img);
    imagedestroy($canvas);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped me

Comment: Dont forget to mark the answer as the right asnwer. Nice to know it worked :)